# Android:- Fragments and Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create a screen with 4 tabs. But initially only first tab have to be seen.

Based on an action in the content ( which is a fragment) I need to create a new tab with different layout. Consider this an application as a form form applying to something. So tabs represents Steps 1,2,3,4. So once I complete the Step 1 I will click on a button which creates a new tab Step2.

I don't want to implement it by launching activities because I need to maintain previous tabs. So how do I catch a button click in a fragment and add a tab at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

```
create a new tab with different layout
```

See this Example
[How do you set Android ViewPager to encompass only one View or Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661499/how-do-you-set-android-viewpager-to-encompass-only-one-view-or-layout/13661761#13661761)

The question is not related to you but Example is Valid and related to One part of your question

EDITED

This is how you can link fragments with your tabs.

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {        
        private int mCount = TABS.length;

        public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            MainSummary f1 = new MainSummary();
            MainActivity f2 = new MainActivity();

            if(TABS[position].equals("Summary")){
                return f1;
            }else if(TABS[position].equals("Activity")){
                return f2;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCount;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TABS[position];
        }
}
```

And for each fragment you can have separate class and layout (`R.layout.main_summary`) like this

```
public final class MainSummary extends ListFragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_summary, container, false); 
    return view; 
}
}
```

There are some useful sample projects here https://github.com/github/android
You can find all answers of your question if you study these samples

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Example given is bit confusing.Can u pls explain what is doing there??